# Opacity property has some problems

Tags: css

I wanted my HTML background opacity to be `.9`, but for some reason it is not working. Why it is happening I really don't understand...

**CSS**

```
html{
  background: url(http://img.pixland.uz/u841f174959.jpg
  ) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1; <!-- if i decrease opacity 1 to 0.9 it will become very small   -->
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/22snQ/)

Comment: Opacity set like this will affect the entire page... why not change the opacity of the image itself?

Comment: If you set the opacity<1 then obviously you webpage will have less sharpness. Instead, in your css, set the opacity to some object or an Image maybe for better effect.

Comment: i want to change whole page opacity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/22snQ/1/)

CSS

```
html,body{
  background: url(http://img.pixland.uz/u841f174959.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
   background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 100%;    
}
```

Comment: what if the OP wants to remove contents from HTML ?!

Comment: i mean what if i want to remove your "aaaaaaaaa" thing ?

Comment: this will set same opacity to html and body. so actual opacity level will be 0.25 in this answer. opacity is one decimal point, but here: set half to html and then another half of that HTML to body, so finally it is 0.25.

Comment: Oh, the "aaaaaaaa" was just to show how the opacity of everything will be changed. It works without it. @JanakaRRajapaksha - That is not the case, remove `body` in the fiddle CSS and you will see there is no visible opacity change.

Comment: @misterManSam, I see it changes opacity after removing body from css fiddle. i use chrome. Am I at a wrong?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/22snQ/

```
html{
    height:100%;
  background: url(http://img.pixland.uz/u841f174959.jpg
  ) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.5; 
}
```

as long as you dont assign height , you are doing it wrong !

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to achieve the desired effect you should change the CSS rules to apply on the **body** tag instead of **html**.Like this:

```
html{ /*Used this to test the opacity thing*/
    background:#000;
}
body{
  background: url(http://img.pixland.uz/u841f174959.jpg
  ) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.5;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

I am searching though, that why won't it work on html tag.